# Semi-complex restructure of directories in linux

Tags: regex, linux, unix, mv

I have a bunch of directories that I need to restructure. They're in a format as such:

```
./1993-02-22 - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL/**files**
./1993-02-23 - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL/**files**
./1993-02-24 - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL/**files**
./1993-02-25 - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL/**files**
./1993-03-01 - The Test - Null, FL/**files**
```

I want to extract the dates from the beginning of each folder. For example, in regex: `([0-9]{4})\-([0-9]{1,2})\-([0-9]{1,2})` and reformat the directories to `./year/month/day`.

So, it should output:

```
./1993/02/22/**files**
./1993/02/23/**files**
./1993/02/24/**files**
./1993/02/25/**files**
./1993/03/01/**files**
```

How can I go about doing that from a command line?

Comment: I suggest writing a shell script. Or using `awk`. (That part is cheating because AWK can do everything but only the Chosen know the correct arcane incantations.)

Comment: @millimoose I guess `sed` could go to your cheating list too. this problem could be solved by sed as well. ;0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood the question in a different way than [Kent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164835/kent). I thought that you wanted to create a new tree of directories from each original one and move all files that it contained. You could try following [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) script if that was what you were looking for:

```
perl -MFile::Path=make_path -MFile::Copy=move -e '
    for ( grep { -d } @ARGV ) {
        @date = m/\A(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/;
        next unless @date;
        $outdir = join q{/}, @date;
        make_path( $outdir );
        move( $_, $outdir );
    }
' *
```

It reads every file from current directory (`*` passed as argument) and does two step filter. The first one is the `grep` for no-directories files and the second one is an undefined `@date` for those that don't begin with it. Then it joins date's components into a path, creates it if doesn't exist and move the old one with all its files to the new one.

A test:

Here the result of `ls -lR` to show initial state:

```
.:
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 dcg dcg 4096 sep  7 00:56 1993-02-22 - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL
drwxr-xr-x 2 dcg dcg 4096 sep  7 00:56 1993-02-23 - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL
drwxr-xr-x 2 dcg dcg 4096 sep  7 00:56 1993-02-24 - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL
drwxr-xr-x 2 dcg dcg 4096 sep  7 00:57 1993-02-25 - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL
drwxr-xr-x 2 dcg dcg 4096 sep  7 00:57 1993-03-01 - The Test - Null, FL
drwxr-xr-x 2 dcg dcg 4096 sep  7 00:47 dummy_dir
-rw-r--r-- 1 dcg dcg    0 sep  7 00:47 dummy_file

./1993-02-22 - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL: 
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 dcg dcg 0 sep  7 00:56 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 dcg dcg 0 sep  7 00:56 file2

./1993-02-23 - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL: 
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 dcg dcg 0 sep  7 00:56 file3

./1993-02-24 - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL: 
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 dcg dcg 0 sep  7 00:56 file4

./1993-02-25 - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL: 
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 dcg dcg 0 sep  7 00:57 file5
-rw-r--r-- 1 dcg dcg 0 sep  7 00:57 file6

./1993-03-01 - The Test - Null, FL: 
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 dcg dcg 0 sep  7 00:57 file7

./dummy_dir:
total 0
```

And after running the previous script note that the base directory only keeps dummy files and the root of the tree created (`1993`). Running the same `ls -lR` yields:

```
.:
total 8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
drwxr-xr-x 4 dcg dcg 4096 sep  7 00:59 1993                                                                                                                                                                                                 
drwxr-xr-x 2 dcg dcg 4096 sep  7 00:47 dummy_dir                                                                                                                                                                                            
-rw-r--r-- 1 dcg dcg    0 sep  7 00:47 dummy_file                                                                                                                                                                                           

./1993:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
total 8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
drwxr-xr-x 6 dcg dcg 4096 sep  7 00:59 02
drwxr-xr-x 3 dcg dcg 4096 sep  7 00:59 03

./1993/02:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 dcg dcg 4096 sep  7 00:56 22
drwxr-xr-x 2 dcg dcg 4096 sep  7 00:56 23
drwxr-xr-x 2 dcg dcg 4096 sep  7 00:56 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 dcg dcg 4096 sep  7 00:57 25

./1993/02/22:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 dcg dcg 0 sep  7 00:56 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 dcg dcg 0 sep  7 00:56 file2

./1993/02/23:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 dcg dcg 0 sep  7 00:56 file3

./1993/02/24:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 dcg dcg 0 sep  7 00:56 file4

./1993/02/25:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 dcg dcg 0 sep  7 00:57 file5
-rw-r--r-- 1 dcg dcg 0 sep  7 00:57 file6

./1993/03:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 dcg dcg 4096 sep  7 00:57 01

./1993/03/01:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 dcg dcg 0 sep  7 00:57 file7

./dummy_dir:
total 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your files are stored in "old" folder, then you may write a shell script (avoid using "for" loop that has difficulties with file names containing spaces):

```
mkdir -p new
ls -d -1 old/*/* | while read oldfile; do
    newfile=`echo "$oldfile" | sed -r 's#^old/([0-9]{4})\-([0-9]{1,2})\-([0-9]{1,2})(.*)$#new/\1/\2/\3/\4#'`
    newdir=` echo $newfile | sed 's#/[^/]*$##'`
    echo "Creating \"$newdir\""
    mkdir -p "$newdir"
    echo "Moving files from \"$oldfile\" to \"$newfile\""
    cp -r "$oldfile" "$newfile"
done
```

output of script:

```
Creating "new/1993/02/22/ - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL"
Moving files from "old/1993-02-22 - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL/test" to "new/1993/02/22/ - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL/test"
Creating "new/1993/02/23/ - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL"
Moving files from "old/1993-02-23 - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL/test" to "new/1993/02/23/ - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL/test"
Creating "new/1993/02/24/ - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL"
Moving files from "old/1993-02-24 - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL/test" to "new/1993/02/24/ - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL/test"
Creating "new/1993/02/25/ - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL"
Moving files from "old/1993-02-25 - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL/test" to "new/1993/02/25/ - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL/test"
Creating "new/1993/03/01/ - The Tes - Null, FL"
Moving files from "old/1993-03-01 - The Tes - Null, FL/test2" to "new/1993/03/01/ - The Tes - Null, FL/test2"
```

and you'll find your new tree in ... the "new" folder indeed:

```
$ tree old new
old
├── 1993-02-22 - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL
│   └── test
├── 1993-02-23 - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL
│   └── test
├── 1993-02-24 - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL
│   └── test
├── 1993-02-25 - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL
│   └── test
└── 1993-03-01 - The Tes - Null, FL
    └── test2
new
└── 1993
    ├── 02
    │   ├── 22
    │   │   └──  - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL
    │   │       └── test
    │   ├── 23
    │   │   └──  - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL
    │   │       └── test
    │   ├── 24
    │   │   └──  - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL
    │   │       └── test
    │   └── 25
    │       └──  - The Moon - Tallahassee, FL
    │           └── test
    └── 03
        └── 01
            └──  - The Tes - Null, FL
                └── test2
```

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
kent$  awk '{gsub(/-/,"/",$1);sub(/^[^/]*\//,"/",$NF);print $1$NF}' file
./1993/02/22/**files**
./1993/02/23/**files**
./1993/02/24/**files**
./1993/02/25/**files**
./1993/03/01/**files**
```

Comment: I'm getting `awk: nonterminated character class ^[^`. Any idea why? Sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `sed+awk` after so much of comments :

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="-"}{print $1"/"$2"/"$3}' file | awk 'BEGIN{FS="**files**"}{print $1"/"FS}' | sed -e 's/ \//\//g'

./1993/02/22/**files**
./1993/02/23/**files**
./1993/02/24/**files**
./1993/02/25/**files**
./1993/03/01/**files**
```